# differential equations of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How may I solve this differential equations:

$$y''+4y=12x^2-16x\cos(2x)?$$

Comment: This is covered in any standard undergraduate ODE text, e.g. Brannon and Boyce or Boyce and DiPrima. The simplest method for this case is probably undetermined coefficients (although the last term will be a little bit annoying with undetermined coefficients).

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset your maths text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Solve the homogeneous part first: the part $y''+4y=0$ by letting $y=e^{\lambda x}$. Then differentiate, substitute, simplify and solve.

Then solve the rest using method of undetermined coefficient.

Comment: Who's marking this post down...is this not a good hint???

Comment: nope it is good, thanks

Comment: +1 because this answer gives some relevant indications of *method* instead of a full explicit solution of this specific differential equation (which might be the reason for the downvote, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the homogeneous part of the equation:

$$ y''+4y$$

Let $y = e^{mx} $, $y' =me^{mx}$, $y'' = m^2e^{mx}$

$$m^2 + 4 = 0$$

$$ m = \pm2i$$
Complementary function:

$$ y = A\cos 2x + B\sin 2x$$

You now need to find the particular integral:

Hint: You may want to try the following function:

$$ y = Ax^2 + Bx + C + (Dx^2 + Ex+F)\cos 2x+ (Gx^2 + Hx+I)\sin 2x$$

Comment: You should have $m^2+4=0$...not $m^2+4m=0$